# Send push notifications when realtime database change

Tags: unity

How to send push notifications (status notifications) from one user to another? I mean a user of a unity MOBILE game to another mobile game? Both uses the SAME  game on their mobiles. 
Thanks!

Comment: To be clear, you want users who are not currently running the app to get notified of changes to a shared database stored on a server somewhere? Or is it sufficient to have users who are currently running the app to be notified?

Comment: @Ed Marty Hello! Allow me please to explain what I want to do with the MOBILE game! The game allows a user to add other players by adding their mobile number to the database and send them some orders like, for example, collecting some coins, finish a certain level..so on . When those players login, for the first time, using their phone number, they get push notifications of the orders asked to finish and when they are done, the first player (the adder) get push notifications. After the first time, whether they are in the app or outside, they get Push notifications.  I want users to

Comment: be able to communicate between themselves and any update in the db, it appers instantly on the game UI inputs. I'm not sure if firebase is suitable or not; I read the firebase allows only the game owner to push notifications to the game users but It's not allowed between users themselves. In addition, firebase has limits and so expensive when upgrading! Is realtime db necessary for my game? What are options to achieve what I want? Many thanks